# PHP Fatal error: Class 'MongoDate' not found

Tags: mongodb, lithium

I use lithium console (lithium/console/li3) to run some command and I get this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoDate' not found`

My system details:

- mongodb server: 2.6.1
- php mongodb client: 1.5.2
- apache 2.4.7
- php 5.5.9-1ubuntu4

`$Requests = Requests::find('all', array('conditions'=>array(
   'expired'=>array('<'=>new \MongoDate(time())),
   'processed'=>0
)));`

I don't have this error while running this code in older version system

- PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11
- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server
- mongodb client: 1.4.5
- mongodb server: 2.4.10

Thank you.

One more thing: I try to create just a simple script

`$date = new MongoDate();`

it runs without problem via webserver (browser) but if I use php command to run this file, I get the same error: `Class 'MongoDate' not found`
So I believe that it's php command problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `mongodb` extension is loaded.

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('mongodb'));
```

If not, you must load it in `php.ini`.

Comment: you are right. I configured the server works only with php-cgi, not cli. So I didn't add the mongodb extension to the cli. After doing that, it works.

Comment: I got mine fixed adding `extension=mongodb.so` to my php.ini of *php-fpm*

Answer (score 30):

For people that have come here using PHP**7**, the classs has been renamed:

`MongoDate` is now `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`

Also I've found that this now wants **miliseconds** instead of **seconds**, so make sure you multiple your input by 1000, for example:

```
$date = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('yesterday') * 1000);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: This helped me very much...Thanks a lot