# FatalErrorException : Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, wampserver

I am using Laravel 5.4. I want use MongoDB.

I installed mongodb version 3.4.4.

And also add extension for wampserver and enabled mongodb extension for php.

Also i tried many extension version for mongodb.dll, but i always get "Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found" Error.

[image]

Pleas help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Class 'MongoDate' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23866598/6521116)

Comment: What version of WAMPServer? Is it 32bit or 64bit? Where did you get the mongo extension? What that 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: [Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169420/6521116)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using wampserver 3.0.6 and 64bit

Comment: Please look here [PHP MongoDB: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261957/php-mongodb-fatal-error-class-mongoclient-not-found). I'm not going to "dupehammer" this, as there seems to be a lot of PHP install problems of late. But please note if it actually solves the issue.

Comment: Then are you sure you downloaded the 64bit Mongo PHP extension?

Comment: Did you also download the TS (Thread Safe) version of the Mongodb PHP extension?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes i am using TS version of the Mongodb extension and I am sure it is downloaded 64bit

Comment: And does the version you download match the version of PHP you are using? Which version of PHP have you got active in your WAMPServer

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using php 5.6 version and also i donwnload and using mongodb extension for that version.

Comment: Try composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I already tried dumb-autoload -o, but still it is same error..